# How to store output from a bash command in a variable

Tags: macos, bash

Hello I am trying to store an OS X command in a variable and I am having problems doing so. Here is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash
Output=$(dscl . -read /Users/root AuthenticationAuthority)
Check="No such key: AuthenticationAuthority"  

if [ "$Output" = "$Check" ]
    then
       echo "OK"
      else
    echo "FALSE"
fi
```

I have done this before with commands such as "defaults read...." and it works fine but the dscl . -read will not store the output in the variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Checked whether its executing?

Comment: When you `echo $Output`, what happens?

Comment: When you run that script do you see the output on your screen? (Is it returning that error to standard error instead of standard output?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On failure, the dscl command, as well as all standard shell commands, outputs the error message on stderr, whereas `$(...)` only captures stdout.

You have to merge the two streams first:

```
Output=$(dscl . -read /Users/root AuthenticationAuthority 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `dscl` command succeeds, its output goes to `stdout`, which is captured by the command substitution.

When there is an error, the message is printed to `stderr` instead.

To capture either `stdout` or `stderr`, you can redirect `stderr` in the command to go to `stdout`:

```
Output=$(dscl . -read /Users/root AuthenticationAuthority 2>&1)
```